# UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPath when to update the model?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, model

I'm implementing a method to remove a row from my tableview based on a domain object but I'm getting a error after call deleteRowsAtIndexPath:animated

> Blockquote Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

So I thought "ok, I'm updating the model too soon". The code:

```
    - (void)deleteItem:(Item *)item {
    NSInteger index = [items indexOfObject:item]; // items is the model a NSArray
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        NSMutableArray *itemEditable = [items mutableCopy];
        [itemEditable removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        self.items = itemEditable; 

        NSIndexPath *indexToDelete = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    }
}
```

And then I change the code to update the model *after* I call deleteRowsAtIndexPath:animated

```
    - (void)deleteItem:(Item *)item {
    NSInteger index = [items indexOfObject:item]; // items is the model a NSArray
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        NSIndexPath *indexToDelete = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];

        NSMutableArray *itemEditable = [items mutableCopy];
        [itemEditable removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        self.items = itemEditable; 

    }
}
```

But it didn't solve, the only thing that changes is the number of rows in the error message from 2 to 3.

> Blockquote Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

Where should I update the model?

---

**Added numberOfRowsInSection method**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [items count];
}
```

Comment: The model should be updated before deleteRowsAtIndexPath.  Can you post the numberOfRowsInSection method?

Comment: Sure I can, just did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem. The setter of items property is implemented to call reloadData and this was causing this confusion.

```
-(void) setItens:(NSMutableArray *)newItens{
    if (itens != nil) {
        [itens release];
        itens = nil;
    }
    itens = [newItens copy];
//  [tableView reloadData]; // WRONG don't do this
}
```

This is the second time I found what I was doing wrong just after publishing the question here. I hope this help someone one day. Thanks aBitObvious, I'm aBitShy now :)

Comment: No worries @Felipe. I heard once about a development company that had a little rubber ducky they kept as an office mascot. The policy was, before you could bother anybody else with a problem you had to explain it to the ducky. And it was amazing how many times the ducky had the solution to the problem! Point is, formulating your problem enough to explain it to someone else often is what it takes to understand it enough yourself to have the necessary "aha" moment.

Answer (score -1):

I think after deleting the row you need to reload it just below the deleted line:

I mean,

```
- (void)deleteItem:(Item *)item 
{
      .......................your code..............

   [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Try this, it should work.

Comment: No, the delete and insert methods already reloadData no need to do this.